# Use of “femme” to mean “girlfriend”

Tags: usage, société

Can *femme* mean *girlfriend*? I just saw a French comedy film in which the main character, a chef, used the term “*ma femme*” and it was always translated in the subtitles as “*my girlfriend*”. The two characters aren't married, though they live together and are expecting a child. They get engaged to be married during the film. So in this circumstance, can *femme* mean *girlfriend* as opposed to *petite amie* or *copine*? I would understand if this were like common-law wife in English, but in the movie, it is clear that they will marry in future.

Comment: Closely related: [How do I designate the person I live with but I'm not married to ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/how-do-i-designate-the-person-i-live-with-but-im-not-married-to)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible. From my personal experience, it appeared a few years ago, mainly in young slang. I suspect that it comes from a further reversing of the older verlan *meuf*. It is still a bit connoted as slang, and *petite amie* and *copine* might be more suitable when talking to older people who might misunderstand it.

Comment: I've done it before we got married 8 years ago.  And we aren't so young (we were in our mid 30's at that time).

Comment: I disagree that it's young slang or derived from *meuf*. I tend to hear it from people over 30 (ok, maybe you consider that young?) and not prone to using *verlan*.

Comment: As I said “from personal experience”. I have never heard it from people over 30.

Comment: Ça m'étonnerait que meuf soit devenu femme. C'est plutôt l'inverse, quand même! Ça fait un baille que cette expression existe.

Answer (score 9):

Traditionally, at least in France (but probably in other French-speaking countries as well), *femme* means *wife*, in the officially married sense. France is traditionally a Catholic country where all marriages are performed by the Catholic Church. The rise of secularism has switched the role of the Church to that of the state, with an state official pronouncing the couple married.

In the late 20th century, official marriages have become rarer, but not living together as a couple. So there are a lot more stable couples who aren't married — what you might call common-law marriage, though the exact concept doesn't exist in France (*[concubinage](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concubinage)* is broader).

The use of the word *femme* to mean effectively a common-law wife (and sometimes dually *mari*) has risen. I hear it used by couples in a stable commitment — almost always living together, potentially having children, and intending to remain together for the foreseeable future. I don't hear it from young people, but rather from couples who have been together for several years and have reached a stable phase in their life. Usually couples do not use the word *femme* and *mari* if they have definite plans to marry; they might use *fiancé(e)* even if they have not undergone any betrothal ceremony, or stick with *copain/copine*.

The situation between men and women is not symmetric because *femme* doubles as meaning *woman* and *wife*. A woman can say *mon homme*, meaning “the man I'm in a stable relationship with”. This usage is older than the use of *femme* to mean “the woman I'm in a stable relationship with”. It doesn't imply marriage or the absence of marriage. Due to the possibility of this alternate wording, using *mari* with no legal marriage is rarer than using *femme* (but not impossible).

When a couple uses *mari/femme*, there is an implication that they are a stable couple and that's all you need to know about them: whether they have made an explicit legal commitment is family business that is not always aired to strangers. The use of *mari/femme* by unmarried couples is a minority usage, but a rising one. If you say “voici ma femme” and you fill in forms where you need to indicate your legal marital status, it may still raise eyebrows if you don't tick the “married” box, but less so over time, especially now that intermediate status of [PACS](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacte_civil_de_solidarit%C3%A9) exists.

People who use the designations *mari/femme* tend to prefer them to *copain/copine* or *petit(e) ami(e)* because these other expressions do not convey stability. You have a *copine* or *petite amie* as a teenager or young adult (whether it's for a month or a decade), but a *femme* as a mature adult in a long-term relationship. Increasingly, this is the difference, and not whether the relationship was made official.

Comment: Although I have heard *femme* in this kind of situation, I have never heard *mari*, but rather *homme*. Considering your comment to my answer, do you think there could be two tendencies *femme* / *homme* and *femme* / *mari* amongst different populations that would happen to concur for *femme*?

Comment: An alternative to _femme_ / _mari_ for non married couples is _compagne_ / _compagnon_

Comment: I stongly agree with Evpok when he says that _mari_ is never used when there is no official mariage. The usage of _femme_ is still rare, but comes from the fact that the distinction _mari/homme_ does not exist for the opposite sex (_femme_ is the only word with these two distinct meanings : _wife/woman_ )

Comment: @Evpok I have heard it, but it is indeed a lot rarer. I don't know enough people to get a statistically significant sample, let alone cross-check with social characterizations.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular context, I think it is the equivalent of calling a boyfriend "mon homme", i.e. "my man", which doesn't suggest a marriage link in either language.

Answer (score 0):

In this context (unmarried, expecting a child, looking forward marriage), *femme* is certainly used these days in France, and have been for more than 20 years now; it would probably be *blonde* in Quebec.

*Copine* is colloquial but could be also heard, particularly toward young people (below 35); it is somewhat less precise. *Petite amie* is also used. Both terms do not carry the same kind of relationship as *femme* however, they can also cover the case for the unstable, early days, where *femme* would not apply.

By the way I am unsure *girlfriend* would be the most used term in English in this context.

Answer (score 0):

What is, in my experience, far more common, is the expression « homme » for "boyfriend." A few years back, there was a radio talk-show host on the french radio station NRJ who went by the name T-miss. She would frequently refer to the female caller's boyfriends as « ton homme. » To me it always felt a lot more charged than the mere « ton copain/petit copain/ami », and implied a more passionate relationship, one where a *masculine principle* and a *feminie principle* clashed in a unpredictable tempest of passion, though I may be the only one to feel this ^^.

Comment: Ils disent la même chose en anglais: "My Man" et "My Woman". (woman = femme).

Comment: C'est vrai, je n'avais pas fait le rapprochement.