# How do I designate the person I live with but I'm not married to ?

Tags: vocabulaire, société

When I speak about my girlfriend with colleagues or my familly, I obviously can't say *“ma femme”* because we're not married. However *“ma copine”* feels odd since we're both adult. What would be an appropriate word for that?

Comment: I've been with her for more than 6 years and we have a 2-years old baby girl but I still call her my "Copine". Being adults, it's obvious to anybody I'm talking about my girlfirend.

Comment: Closely related: [Use of “femme” to mean “girlfriend”](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/use-of-femme-to-mean-girlfriend)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Compagne* is the most commonly used, it implies you are in a long standing relationship and that you live together as a couple under the same roof.

If you do not live as a couple under the same roof you can say *mon amie*, as long as the context is sufficient to make clear what kind of *amie* she is.

The use of *copine* is not restricted to children and young people. You can very well have a person in an old people's home speaking of their *copain* or *copine*. It's more a question of state or mind than of generation. Using *copain/copine* does not necessarily imply living as a couple under the same roof.

Those who do not want to use *copine* can use *petite amie* (sounds a bit old fashioned to me). Fifty or more years ago people would use the phrase *bonne amie*, but it is hardly ever used nowadays, people understand though.

Comment: You can also said _concubin_/_concubine_

Comment: @IronRabbit *Concubin* is a legal term that one would only use to stress any financial or legal aspect of a union.In Québec I think *concubin* is called *conjoint de fait*.  And in any case both *concubin* and *conjoint de fait* are only used in the case of a long standing relationship implying both parties live under one roof.

Comment: @Laure I'm not exactly sure how *concubin* is used in France, but simply *conjoint* is definitely used in Québec in every day talk. It means pretty much the same as *conjoint de fait* does on paper, though some people prefer it to *mari/femme*.

Comment: @Kareen  *Concubin* in France implies the couple is neither married nor [pacsed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_solidarity_pact) but [*concubinage*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concubinage)  is in some legal instances a recognized form of union between two individuals.  *Conjoint* is only used for married couples in France.

Answer (score 4):

Au Canada on parle de *conjoint* (qui a un sens un peu plus large, incluant les gens mariés). Si on veux exclure précisément les gens mariés, on parle d'une *blonde* et d'un *chum*.

Enfin, s'il s'agit seulement d'une personne avec qui on partage un appartement sans relation romantique, c'est un ou une *colocataire*.

Answer (score 2):

Well *femme*/*homme* is used, even when not married (*mari* is never used in absence of marriage, *femme* is not unheard in absence of marriage, but rare in this context, *homme* is relatively rare to designate a romantic partner, but has no implication of marriage).  *Ami/amie*, *copain/copine*, *compagnon/compagne* are also used with small nuances (*femme/homme* and *compagnon/compagne* mostly implies that you live together for instance).

For words like *ami/amie*, *copain/copine* which leaves some ambiguity (*compagnon/compagne* doesn't), what seems to be important is the use of the possessive.  If you introduce your girlfriend with ***mon** amie*, ***ma** copine* the nature of the relationship will be clear.  If you introduce a girl friend with ***une** amie*, ***une** copine* the nature of the relationship will also be clear.

Comment: Femme / homme ? "Ma femme" est clairement un terme réservé aux gens mariés. "Mon homme" n'est pas un équivalent de "Mari" et bien que je l'ai entendu, il s'agit plutôt d'une référence général à un conjoint plutôt qu'à un statut de non marié.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, j'ai clarifié (mais si _femme_ est généralement utilisé en cas de marriage, le terme n'est pas réservé aux épouses dans l'usage que je constate).

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec conjoint(e) peut ou non inclure un statut marital légal. C'est une terminologie maintenant dominante traduisant le fait que les couples ne sont plus majoritairement  légalement et encore moins religieusement mariés.  Il signifie strictement la personne avec qui on partage sa vie. S'applique à toutes les orientations sexuelles. Chum ou blonde est beaucoup plus familier.