# boyfriend in French

Tags: vocabulaire

I know two translations for "boyfriend" in French: copain m, petit ami m.

In English it means a romantic and intimate partner without marriage.

I am studying the difference between them.

copain = "ancien français compain, cas sujet de compagnon" - Larousse

What is the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: *Copain* and *petit ami* are not the only possible translations. You should consider, *mec*, *compagnon*, *bon ami*, and maybe a few more, they can all translate "boyfriend" according context (mainly how deep  the relationship is and age of the person using the word). A quick search on French Language would have lead you to this [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/12465/358) to help you with yours. A *copain* is originally the one with who the bread (*pain*) is shared.

Answer (score 3):

We used to say "*petit ami*" and "*petit copain*", but there are a little aged now. "*Petit ami*" is fine if you're talking to your parents or older, but "*petit copain*" sound reaaaally old.

"*Petit copain*" became "*copain*". "*Ami*" still means friend. "*Mec*" is also used a lot.

It sounds like it's hard to tell the difference between friend and boyfriend but really it isn't :

> Je suis venue avec **mon** copain vs Je suis venue avec **un** copain/pote

(I came with **my** boyfriend vs I came with **a** friend (of mine, implicitly)

> J'ai croisé **un** mec dans la rue vs J'ai croisé **mon** mec dans la rue

(I bumped into **a** guy in the street vs I bumped into **my** boyfriend in the street)

Basically, it's the **possession** that tells "boyfriend" apart from "friend". See also :

> **J'ai** un mec

(I **have** a boyfriend, marks possession as well)

---

The same applies for "girlfirend" : "*Copine*" is the most common, "*petite amie*" is dated but not that bad, and the "equivalent" of "*mec*" is "*meuf*", but it's a little more casual and vulgar, don't use it with anyone.

Comment: You suggest “un mec” as a way to avoid ambiguity when using “un” is unavoidable (as in your example, when **stating** that one has a boyfriend) & fwiw, I totally agree.  If you don’t mind fielding a follow-up, would using “un mec” also be a good unambiguous way to familiarly **ask** someone: “As-tu un mec?” (or would it be better to use something more formal like “As-tu quelqu'un dans ta vie?”)?-(“As-tu un jules?” did briefly cross my mind as an option for asking that question, but that would be even more ambiguous! “Do you have a chamber pot?” or even worse, “Do you have a pimp?”) Thanks & +1

Comment: @PapaPoule Thank you ! But actually, maybe it's not clear but I'm still showing possession when using *un* : "**J'ai** un mec". (=="c'est **le mien**") Maybe it's the "see also" that is confusing, I looked for another word but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Ahh, ok yes, I did kind of misinterpret your reason for including “J’ai un mec” but that was totally my fault because the ‘j’ai” does clearly mark possession just as “As-tu” would mark it when encountered in the form of a question.

Comment: Nice anwser. Just a thing I noted, you say *Ami* still means *Friend*. While I find this a bit ridiculous, I know some people who do use *Ami* to say boyfriend. Just a few weeks ago I was in a carpool and the driver told me about his *amie* that he was going to visit. And he was obviously talking about his girlfriend.

Comment: "J'ai un ami" is ambiguous "I have a friend" or "I have a boyfriend" when "J'ai un petit ami" ou "J'ai un petit copain" only mean "I have a boyfriend".

"J'ai un copain" it depends of the age of the one who says that, under 13 it means a friend, over it means a boyfriend.

"J'ai un mec" only means a boyfriend, but it is really familiar.

Don't know why you meant it is old but "petit copain" is still used a lot. The first example is when you chat with a girl and she answer you "J'ai déjà un petit copain".

Comment: @JulianColin It also depends on context. You don't say "*J'ai un copain*" in every situation. If you say it alone, there is no reason to mention that you have a friend so it'll mean boyfriend, but if you say "*J'ai un copain qui va arriver*" it's clear that it's a friend. For a boyfriend it would be "*J'ai mon copain qui va arriver*".

Comment: @JulianColin It could be ambiguous if for example at a party, several people bring one of their friends who don't know each other, then you have to refer to yours as "my friend". Then it's preferable to say "pote" or "ami" for no confusion.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat yes I agree, I tried to make it simple, but in fact it is not ... The easiest way would be to use "ami" or "pote" (a bit familiar) for friends, and "petit copain" or "petit ami" for boyfriend, It is the less ambiguous way, but it will never be perfect, the context is important.