# Copain/copine : quand signifient-ils relations amoureuses/sexuelles ?

Tags: synonymes, france

Aujourd'hui pendant le déjeuner **une collègue** a dit :

> Avec *ma copine*, nous sommes allées...

Ici, le mot copine signifie-t-il **conjointe/compagne** ?

Parmi les locuteurs natifs à qui j'ai posé la question il n'y avait pas de consensus. Certains m'ont dit que copain/copine peut signifier même **accointance** sans nécessairement rapport amoureux/sexuel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I designate the person I live with but I'm not married to ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/how-do-i-designate-the-person-i-live-with-but-im-not-married-to)

Comment: @Unfrancophone Merci. Ma question porte sur le mot copain/copine. Je ne vois pas le duplicate.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Je viens d'éditer. J'espère être plus clair maintenant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que ça dépend des personnes, mais pour moi dans ton exemple, il ne fait aucun doute que tu parles de ta compagne. Introduire le nom avec un adjectif possessif implique forcément cette relation sentimentale...

... sauf s'il est suivi par un autre qualificatif :

> avec ma copine Nathalie
>
> avec ma copine institutrice
>
> avec ma copine de travail
>
> avec ma copine japonaise

Dans tous ces cas, c'est le contraire, il est très probable que tu ne parles pas de ta compagne. Si tu voulais parler de ta compagne, tu devrais dire :

> avec ma copine, (qui s'appelle) Nathalie
>
> avec ma copine, (qui est) institutrice
>
> avec ma copine, que j'ai rencontrée au travail
>
> avec ma copine, (qui est) japonaise

Avec un article indéfini, aucun doute que ce n'est pas ta compagne (*avec une copine*).

Il n'y a que les enfants, à mon sens, qui utilise *ma copine* sans rien après pour parler d'une relation amicale.

Mais je suis sûr qu'il y a des exemples contradictoires avec ce que je viens de dire, et je rappelle que c'est un ressenti personnel.

Comment: On peut aussi préciser que *petit copain/petite copine* n'est par contre jamais ambigu et désigne nécessairement l'amoureux/se (et n'est pas lié à la taille de la personne).

Comment: Je pense que c'est très importante de note que c'est uniquement "**introduire** le nom" ! Si la copine en question a déjà été introduite (pas *une copine* par exemple), on peut ensuite utiliser *ma copine*. Par exemple : "*Je suis allé dans un bar avec **une copine**, [...] et le barman offert un verre à **ma copine**!*". L'amie est introduite avec *une*, mais un fois qu'on sait que ce n'est pas sa compagne ça ferait bizarre de continuer à utiliser *une copine*.

Answer (score 6):

*Copain*/*copine*, comme *ami*/*amie*, sont en pratique ambigus.  Généralement quand on introduit la personne dans la conversation avec un possessif c'est qu'il y a une relation sentimentale mais ce n'est pas toujours vrai, en particulier quand il s'agit de personnes de même sexe.  Si la personne n'a pas été introduite avec un possessif, il n'y a a mon avis aucun doute, il ne s'agit pas d'une relation sentimentale.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que si une collègue de travail vous a effectivement dit cela ("avec  ma copine, ..."), cela signifie beaucoup plus que si elle vous avait dit "avec  une copine, ...". En fait le possessif "ma" signifie réellement une relation particulière, pas nécessairement sexuellement connotée. Ceci pour dire que le mot le plus important dans cette phrase n'est pas copine, mais "ma".

Answer (score 0):

Ce terme, copain/copine, n'a jamais été utilisé de façon très importante avec la signification de « amoureux » ; c'est un usage qui n'a fait que prendre de l'ampleur récemment, dans les décades passées, c'est à dire bien plus tard que lorsqu'il a commencé à remplacer le mot « ami » (1960, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copain%2Ccopine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccopain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopine%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccopain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopine%3B%2Cc0)). De toute ma jeunesse passée en France (1950-1975) je n'ai jamais entendu  quelqu'un le dire dans le sens de « amoureux » ; cela ne signifie pas que tout au moins l'idée n'existait pas puisque selon les exemples du [TLFi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copain%2Ccopine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccopain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopine%3B%2Cc0) on peut remonter jusqu'à 1927.

> 2. Amoureux, amant :
>
>    - Je rencontre aussi, tous les soirs, une petite putain, peinte et poudrée. Elle est amputée d'une cuisse et marche avec des béquilles. (...). Il paraît que cette personne a des amateurs : Chaque jour elle change de copain.
>        G. DUHAMEL, Journal de Salavin, 1927, p. 115.
>    - Il lui dit : Quand j'avais seize ans seize ans, vous entendez, j'avais une petite copine de quatorze ans. Je l'aimais comme on aime pour la première fois, c'est-à-dire avec un feu qu'on ne retrouvera jamais plus.
>        MONTHERLANT, Les Jeunes filles, 1936, p. 1069.

On peut remarquer que dans les exemples le terme n'apparait pas avec une spécificité de définition certaine ; « chaque jour elle change de copain » confère une idée dans laquelle on peut difficilement parler d'amour et « copain » peut n'être alors que rien de plus qu'un euphémisme pour « jules » ou une façon plus réaliste de décrire la relation. Dans le second cas, de même, il s'agit de très jeunes personnes et l'amitié est quelque chose qui est un précurseur dans ce cas, en particulier dans le siècle passé : d'abord copain puis amoureux.

On peut conclure, je crois, qu'en tant qu'usage assez substantiel il est  véritablement récent et il n'est toujours pas généralisé ; comme dans le cas mentionné dans la question originelle il va prêter à confusion et beaucoup de monde continuera à se garder de donner cours à l'ambiguïté qu'il traine avec lui.

Personnellement, je vois cet usage comme conséquence de l'élan irréfléchi d'une section de la population en  besoin de remplir le vide que laissent les termes traditionnels qui ne sont plus ressentis comme adéquats dans leur description des relations considérées. Il existe donc encore une fois une impasse dans la langue et encore une fois, apparemment, elles sera résolue non pas dans la concertation mais dans l'irrationalité des caprices populaires.

Comment: On peut connaitre la raison du vote négatif ?

Comment: Peut-être pour le dernier paragraphe qui se perd en gloses pompeuses, hautaines et inutiles ("irrationalité des caprices populaires") ?

Comment: @Greg C'est entièrement une affaire d'opinion et je le mentionne ; ça ne justifie pas un vote négatif comme rien n'a été prouvé faux et il m'a d'ailleurs été dit que l'on peut formuler une opinion si on est clair sur le point que c'est bien  ce dont il s'agit. Quant à la pomposité et la nature hautaine des termes ce n'est que fumée d'opinion, la votre. S'il me vient l'idée de dire blanc en prétendant que c'est noir et en vous demandant de changer votre façon de voir vous aurez tôt fait de me rappeler que votre langage ne peut pas être sujet à mes caprices. Il n'y a pas de différence.